# How to track response time of transactions in iOS app

Tags: android, ios, instruments

Tracing the response time of iOS app how to do it using instrument.
Also looking for a tool or way to capture response time of critical transactions in android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to logging the time using NSLog like this:

```
//log the time
NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];

//Do your transaction and when success execute ...

NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
NSLog(@"Total time = %f", executionTime);
```